# Multicore thread processing

Tags: operating-system, multicore

I understand that in Multicore environment, different threads are executed in parallel by OS scheduler. In a single core environment, context switching enables processing of high priority tasks and when an hardware interrupt occurs, ISR is given utmost priority.Is there any context switching criteria for assigning threads to different cores in multicore environment.In other words, when a hardware interrupt occurs which core among the many core is interrupted for ISR execution? How does OS choose one among many possible cores in multi core environment for high priority execution?

Comment: first off too many questions, second way too vague there isnt a way to answer this at this site.

Comment: It wouldnt make sense for multiple cores to get the same interrupt in general.  But as to which core, it is the core that the programmer chose to get the interrupt.  Likewise as to how to choose which core to do something, it varies by programmer/team and no reason to assume any two solutions work the same.